# Adding buttons to Fragments dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button

I have been trying to add buttons to my fragment dynamically but all the methods I have tried somehow doesnt work.

These are some methods I have tried:

1.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        linearlayout.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        button.setText("????????????????????");
        button.setTextSize(16);

        Button button2 = new Button(getActivity());
        button2.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        button2.setText("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        button2.setTextSize(64);

        linearlayout.addView(button);
        linearlayout.addView(button2);

        container.addView(linearlayout);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_layout, container, false);

 return myView;

    }
```

This will give me the following screenshot [First method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abyHG.png).
I really dont like this as this will create a button on the Activity itself which would appear on my other Fragments that are using the same Activity.

2. For second method

`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_layout, container, false);


            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfNames.length; i++) {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btn = new Button(myView.getContext());
                btn.setId(i);
                final int id_ = btn.getId();
                btn.setText(ArrayOfNames[i]);
                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                linearlayout.addView(btn, params);
                btn = myView.findViewById(id_);

                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            //do smth


                    }
                });
return myView;
}
```

This method I assume will make the buttons (as the code runs fine and at least the buttons are not having a null pointer references when setting the OnClickListner(). **But I cant see** actual buttons on my screen. Also, not possible to click on it.

I tried to reference from these 
urls: [Programmatically add buttons to a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963818/programmatically-add-buttons-to-a-fragment)

[Adding buttons programmatically to a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066847/adding-buttons-programmatically-to-a-fragment)

[How to add a button programmatically to a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807982/how-to-add-a-button-programmatically-to-a-fragment?lq=1)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of adding the buttons dynamically, add all the buttons you need in the XML but keep their visibility GONE. Make them visible as and when required. This will require a much less code, you will have a better control over which buttons to show and which ones to hide and you can also unit test your logic of displaying and hiding the buttons.

Comment: @Ezio Thanks but that sounds like extremely long XML file and I dont really want such a long code especially when I have like 50 buttons. That was the method I first tried then was improving on it to the current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I have manged to do it. The second method had problem as there is no

`btn = myView.findViewById(id_);`. 
This will be pointing to null although I have set my button's ID to be the value I stated. Using this method, it is easy to still get the value of the button by setting a separate `onClick()` method.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfNames.length; i++) {

                final Button myButton = new Button(myView.getContext());
                myButton.setText(RAnames[i]);
                myButton.setId(i + 1);
                myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                myButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                myButton.setTextSize(18);
                myButton.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);

                LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnholder);
                linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                buttonParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);

                linearlayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onCreateView` method expects you to return the view which you are inflating. Your code is good, but you're adding the buttons to the wrong view. Try this instead:

```
//container.addView(linearlayout);
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_layout, container, false);
myView.addView(linearlayout);
```

This should add your buttons to your view. I'm assuming that your `R.layout.fragment_general_layout` is a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"`

Comment: erm myView is a type View which does not have a addView method. Any other ideas? :) Thanks for the input though.